# CC.NET & SVN: Cannot 'GetModifications' - source control failure

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net

I'm preparing our new CC.NET server. After the migration of the `ccnet.config` from our old build server, we experience an error when building one of our projects.
All defined projects with a single source-control element work well. But one project that relies upon multi-source-control won't build.
An extract of our configuration:

```
<sourcecontrol type="multi" >
  <sourceControls>
    <svn autoGetSource="false">
      <trunkUrl>http://sourceserver/svn/projecXYZ/dev/client</trunkUrl>
      <workingDirectory>C:\dev\projecXYZ\dev\client</workingDirectory>
      <cleanCopy>false</cleanCopy>
      <timeout units="hours">1</timeout>
    </svn>
    <svn autoGetSource="false">
      <trunkUrl>http://sourceserver/svn/projecXYZ/dev/server/include</trunkUrl>
      <workingDirectory>C:\dev\projecXYZ\dev\server\include</workingDirectory>
      <cleanCopy>false</cleanCopy>
      <timeout units="hours">1</timeout>
    </svn>
  </sourceControls>
</sourcecontrol>
```

This leads to the following error:

```
Source control failure (GetModifications): Value cannot be null. Parameter name: s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you having the problem in CruiseControl.NET 1.8.4? We encountered it when trying to upgrade from CruiseControl.NET 1.8.3 to CruiseControl.NET 1.8.4, on the MultiSourceControl for svn. Regular SVN is OK.

Looks like this issue was fixed in a patch from 5 months ago on 09/12/2013. However 1.8.4 was put together on 09/01/2013. It should be fixed in the next release of CruiseControl.NET 1.8.5:

- [Issue 303 - ArgumentNullException on multi source GetModifications()](http://cruisecontrolnet.org/issues/303)
- [Issue 304 - ArgumentNullException when using MultiSourceControl with svn](http://cruisecontrolnet.org/issues/304)
- [Issues fixed for 1.8.5](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/issues?fixed_version_id=11&per_page=100&set_filter=1&status_id=%2a)

Comment: Yes, it occures in 1.8.4.
I saw the issues, too. Now we are using a nightly build - I think it is 1.9.48. This "solves" the issue for now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the "tags" for svn task have changed.

http://build.sharpdevelop.net/ccnet/doc/CCNET/Subversion%20Source%20Control%20Block.html

```
<sourcecontrol type="svn">
  <trunkUrl>svn://svn.mycompany.com/myfirstproject/trunk</trunkUrl>
  <workingDirectory>c:\dev\ccnet</workingDirectory>
</sourcecontrol>
```

I would try to put 2 simple file-copies inside your multi blocks, then move over to svn.

```
<filesystem>
  <!-- Check for changes in the latest 1.2 version of the server... -->
  <repositoryRoot>\\DistributionFileServer\Server\1.2.latest</repositoryRoot>
</filesystem>
```

Comment: Nope, the child elements in the `<sourceControls>`-collection need to be like the type: so a normal `<sourcecontrol type="svn">` becomes `<svn>` like said in the [documentation](http://build.sharpdevelop.net/ccnet/doc/CCNET/Multi%20Source%20Control%20Block.html). I'll give the `<filesystem>` approach a try...

Comment: Ok, you learn something new every day.  Yeah, now I'm curious.